# Convert SharePoint Page to PDF

Tags: asp.net, pdf, sharepoint, export-to-pdf, pdf-conversion

Over the past couple of days, I have been struggling to convert SharePoint Pages to PDF. Below one is my code. Used `HttpWebRequest` to read page content into HTML and converting HTML to pdf by using [SelectPdf converter](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Convert-from-HTML-to-PDF-09ce2a1d#content).

It converting text but layouts and images are missing. Please suggest best possibilities.

```
string urlAddress = "<Here SP Page URL>";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);
request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader readStream = null;

    if (response.CharacterSet == null)
    {
        readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
    }
    else
    {
        readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
    }
    string strdata = readStream.ReadToEnd();

    response.Close();
    readStream.Close();

    using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\testPage1.html"))
    {                     
        file.Write(strdata);   
    }

    HtmlToPdf converter = new HtmlToPdf();

    PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertHtmlString(strdata);
    HtmlToPdfResult result = converter.ConversionResult;

    // save pdf document
    doc.Save(Response, false, "Sample12.pdf");

    // close pdf document
    doc.Close();
```

Comment: when you open testpage1.html in a browser, is the layout ok?

Comment: The HTML Converter will try to resolve the images (and CSS, And JS, and many other resource) against your local drive rather than your SharePoint domain. As a result it cannot find it. You are in a potential world of pain here, please consider 3rd party SharePoint software that specialises in this if you have the budget.